# crosss compile for ARM7 : error: '__int128' is not supported for this target

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling

```
typedef unsigned __int128 uint128_t;

static uint64_t mul64hi(uint64_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    return (uint64_t) ((((__int128) x) * ((__int128) y)) >> 64);
}
```

Comment: What is not clear????... Error is crystal...

Comment: @LPs maybe it was the shock of getting a compiler error message that was succinct and understandable without reading through a pagefull of paths and other gunge.

Answer (score 0):

It is what it is. A C compiler is not required to support a 128 bit integral type, and your platform seems to be such an instance, or if it does, it's not `__int128`. (Try `__int128_t` or `int128_t`?)

Consult your compiler documentation for absolute certainty,  or consider using a 3rd party large integer library, e.g. https://gmplib.org/